# Is it possible for density in pounds per cubic foot, times a volume, to equal a force in pounds?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, work

In the Calculus book "Calculus: Early Transcendentals" by Edwards and Penney, 7th Edition, there is a chapter on Force and Work. In particular, there is a section explaining how to calculate the work done when filling a tank with fluid.

The assumptions of the problem are:

- the tank is filled in thin, horizontal layers of fluid, each lifted from its ground position to its final position in the tank
- the bottom of the tank is at height $y=a$ and its top at height $y=b>a$.
- $A(y)$ is the cross-sectional area of the tank at height $y$

The solution of the problem:

- partition $[a,b]$ into n subintervals of length $ \Delta y$
- the volume of the i-th horizontal slice is thus $\Delta V_i = \int_{y_{i-1}}^{y_i} A(y)dy = A(y_i^*) \Delta y$ for some $y_i^*$ in $[y_{i-1}, y_i]$ (the last equality follows from the average value theorem for integrals, on the interval $[y_{i-1}, y_i]$

**Now here is the part I don't understand, and I think it probably has to do with confusion regarding the system of measurement**

> suppose $ \rho $ is the density of the fluid (**in pounds per cubic
> foot, for example)**, then the force required to lift this slice from the ground to its final position in the tank is simply the (constant) weight of the slice: $$F_i= \rho \Delta V_i = \rho A(y_i^*) \Delta y$$

I see a density times a volume, giving a mass in pounds (which to me is the counterpart to the kilogram unit of mass if we are in a metric system). I googled and found out that indeed there is a unit called a pound of force, which is defined as the force that accelerates 1 pound of mass at 9.80665 meters per second square.

How is the expression above for force a force and not just a mass?

[image: Picture of the problem]

Comment: Abusive notation like that makes me shudder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the expression above for force a force and not just a mass?

It's clearly just a mass, but the author seems to be abusing the fact that the proportionality constant between *pounds* - as in mass - and *pounds of force* is $g = 1\,\frac{\mathrm{lbf}}{\mathrm{lb}}$.

So the correct expression for a force would be
$$ F_i= g \, \rho \, \Delta V_i $$
which holds in any unit system, not just the $\mathrm{lb/lbf}$ version.